# cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ScrubAddress'

Tags: xml, xsd

Keep getting this error: 
cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ScrubAddress'.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<ScrubAddress>

<pstrAddr1>1310 dusk</pstrAddr1>

<pstrAddr2/>

<pstrZip>61801</pstrZip>

</ScrubAddress>
```

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
  <xs:element name="ScrubAddress">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="pstrAddr1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="pstrAddr2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
       <xs:element name="pstrZip" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with your schema or instance document, there's something wrong with the way you are invoking the validation process. You need to tell us more about what schema processor you are using and how you are running it.

Comment: Sorry i am so new at this i am not sure what that means.

Comment: What were you doing when you got the error?

Comment: So this app i have scrubs address,, when i use soupUI it works and i get information back right, however i get this error message back in the Stderr log.